# Instantiated object doesn't contain colliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a script that Instantiates a ball when called. However the balls `RigidBody2D` and `Collider2D` are already in the scene upon build, prior to Instantiation. Why is this happening?

**Ball Script:**

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 10;
    void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        Launch();
        this.gameObject.name = "Ball";
        BoxCollider boxCollider = gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
        Rigidbody2D gameObjectsRigidBody = this.gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void Launch()
    {
        //code used to determine in which direction the ball should go when it spawns
        float x = Random.Range(0, 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
        float y = Random.Range(0, 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * x, speed * y);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A few questions arose to me upon first inspection: 
Why are you getting the Rigidbody2D fist and then adding another one again? Why are you adding a BoxCollider (which is relevant in 3D) to an object with a 2D rigidbody? Why does your prefab not provide the components in the first place? Could it be that your ball in the scene has unapplied changes?

Comment: Where and how do you spawn that ball? Why don't you simply attach all required components on the prefab already?

Comment: @MaxPlay is heading in the right direction.  You seem to be putting another Rigidbody on your object, not really sure what would happen.  Second rule of thumb - never put "execution" code in `Awake` , always place it in `Start`. (i.e. move `Launch()` to `Start`).  The only thing that should ever go into `Awake` is setup code, like the other tasks you are doing in `Awake`

Comment: To add to @jiveturkey: Think of `Awake()` as a parameterless constructor, but `Start()` of the first iteration of `Update()` where everything else is already initialized in an object.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong, the instantiated prefab was not going into the start function, so I moved everything into the awake function and then the colliders didn't work

Comment: Thankyou for all the comments as I know what the problem is so I might delete this post and repost something else

Answer (score 0):

The `Awake` function will be called even if the program is disabled. Therefore the `RigidBody2D` and `Collider2D` were already instantiated and were not updated. You should move the code from `Awake` to `Start` and enable the script using the **snippet below:**

```
private Scriptname script;

private void Awake()
{
    script = GetComponent<ScriptName>();
    script.enabled = true;
}
```

More info on this subject [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/516812/enable-a-script-on-object-in-c-help.html)